# How to denote a vector of vectors?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, vectors

Say I have an element of a tuple $$(\boldsymbol{x},p)$$
where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a vector $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ...)$ and $p$ is a scalar.

They form a vector $$((\boldsymbol{x},p)_{1}, \; (\boldsymbol{x},p)_{2}, \; ...)$$
which I would like to write shorthand as
$$\boldsymbol{(\boldsymbol{x},p)}$$
However then the fact that $\boldsymbol{x}$ is lost.

I would not want to use the notation
$$(\boldsymbol{x},p)_{i}$$

**Question**: how do I write $((\boldsymbol{x},p)_{1}, \; (\boldsymbol{x},p)_{2}, \; ...)$ in short bold clear vector notation?

Comment: How about $((x_i, p) : 1 \le i \le n)$?

Comment: Do you have several "versions" of $\boldsymbol{x}$, each coupled with a different $p$, i.e. $(\boldsymbol{x}, p)_i = (\boldsymbol{x}_i, p_i)$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes, $\boldsymbol{x}$ is effectively a variate rather than a variable; and your equality is correct. The collection of 2-tuples is meant to represent a multi-variate probability mass function, where for each variate $\boldsymbol{x_{i}} = (x_{11}.x_{12},...)$ there is a probability $p_{i}$.